# How to Sum (MAX values) from different value groups in same column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, max

I have a table like this:

| Date | Consec_Days |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | 1 |
| 2015-01-03 | 1 |
| 2015-01-06 | 1 |
| 2015-01-07 | 2 |
| 2015-01-09 | 1 |
| 2015-01-12 | 1 |
| 2015-01-13 | 2 |
| 2015-01-14 | 3 |
| 2015-01-17 | 1 |

I need to Sum the max value (days) for each of the consecutive groupings where Consec_Days are > 1. So the correct result would be 5 days.

Comment: Only for 2 consecutive days? If there was a row for 2015-01-15 what would the result be?

Comment: can be for more than 2 groups of consecutive days. So if there was 2015-01-15 the result would be 6 = the sum of max consecutive days per consecutive day group

Answer (score 0):

**This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions, here is one simple one

- Get the start points of each group using `LAG`
- Calculate a grouping ID using a windowed conditional count
- Group by that ID and take the highest sum

```
WITH StartPoints AS (
    SELECT *,
      IsStart = CASE WHEN LAG(Consec_Days) OVER (ORDER BY Date) = 1 THEN 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
),
Groupings AS (
    SELECT *,
      GroupId = COUNT(IsStart) OVER (ORDER BY Date)
    FROM StartPoints
    WHERE Consec_Days > 1
)
SELECT TOP (1)
  SUM(Consec_Days)
FROM Groupings
GROUP BY
  GroupId
ORDER BY
  SUM(Consec_Days) DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c712824cf95298ffbc24d42e40d7da93)

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
select  Consec_Days,
    coalesce(lead(Consec_Days) over (order by Date), 1) as next
from    YourTable
)
select sum(Consec_Days)
from cte
where Consec_Days <> 1 and next = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0140237f97c877eb52097e80f1dbf349)